# Fetching data with parameter from one table to another

Tags: oracle, adempiere

I would like to fetch data from one table to another, given the parameter below..

So I have 4 tables, they are

```
M_InternalRequester, M_InternalRequesterLine, M_Inventory, M_InventoryLine
```

**M_InternalRequester**

```
-----------------------
m_internalrequester_id 
-----------------------
1001
```

**M_InternalRequesterLine**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
m_internalrequesterline_id || m_internalrequester_id || m_product_id || qty || 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3001                       || 1001                   || 21001        ||  3  ||
3002                       || 1001                   || 21002        ||  4  ||
```

**M_Inventory**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
m_inventory_id || description             || m_internalrequester_id ||
----------------------------------------------------------------------
8001           || Referred from Internal  ||  1001                  ||
```

**M_InventoryLine**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
m_inventoryline_id || m_inventory_id || m_product_id || qty || 
--------------------------------------------------------------
???????????        ||  8001          ||  ??????????? || ??  ||
???????????        ||  8001          ||  ??????????? || ??  ||
```

I have data that previously recorded in `M_Internal Requester` and `M_InternalRequesterLine`

I would like to fetch data from `M_InternalRequesterLine` to `M_InventoryLine`, based on the parameter `m_internalrequester_id` given in table `M_Inventory`

I've made a trigger like this

```
create or replace trigger TG_AI_M_INVENTORYSN
before update on m_inventory
for each row
declare
  internalrequester_id number;
  invline_id number;

CURSOR c1 is
select
    M_PRODUCT_ID, QTY
from m_internalrequesterline
where m_internalrequester_id=:new.m_internalrequester_id;

BEGIN

if inserting then 
SELECT M_INTERNALREQUESTER_ID INTO INTERNALREQUESTER_ID FROM M_INTERNALREQUESTER WHERE
m_internalrequester_ID = :new.m_internalrequester_id;

FOR insertline in C1
LOOP
select currentnext into invline_id from AD_Sequence WHERE
name = 'M_Inventoryline';

INSERT INTO M_INVENTORYLINE 

(m_inventoryline_id, m_product_id, qty
)
VALUES 
(invline_id, insertline.m_product_id, insertline.qty);


update AD_Sequence set currentnext=invline_id+1 where name = 'M_Inventoryline';
END LOOP;
END IF;


end;
```

It was created but when I execute it won't work. What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger according to this declaration:

```
create or replace trigger TG_AI_M_INVENTORYSN
before update on m_inventory
```

so the trigger is fired only before update statements.

---

The IF statement is using `INSERTING` predicate to check if a trigger is fired after or before INSERT statement.

```
if inserting then ....
```

---

Because the trigger is fired only before UPDATE, the INSERTING predicate is always false, and a code between `THEN` and `END IF` is never executed.